# Email template 'customemail_email_template' is not defined. in magento2

Tags: magento2

hello everyone i am sending mail to admin form details it is

> Getting error : Email template 'customemail_email_template' is not
>   defined.

The link i have referred :
http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/sending-custom-emails-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

The thing was that Post.php file should be under

> “app/code/Codextblog/Customemail/Controller/Index” directory, not in
>   the “app/code/Codextblog/Customemail/Controller”.

Comment: it is undor index

Comment: see the comment in the post : http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/sending-custom-emails-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: someone also getting the same error and the above answer resolved that issue as according to the comment in that post

Comment: can you please tell the name

Answer (score 0):

Sending a Custom Email is very easy and can be done through a generated module.

Take a look at this example module which has a configuration option with a custom email template and a basic helper to send the email.

> https://mage2gen.com/load/e4822a13-a700-4372-b5d0-9704cf436f8d?main_version=2

[image]